# Rails: Mixing different models in one Index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 different models: Recommendation and Article. Instead of categorizing them, I want to display them together in an index view
, something like:

```
  #recommendations and articles instances are all stored to @postables
  @postables.each do
    #if is Recommendation, then render recommendation partial
    #if is article, then render article partial
```

I want to put them together in certain order( likes number, created_on, etc.)

An ugly approach would be

```
  @postales= Recommendation.all + Article.all
  @postables.order()
  if postable.class?('Artile')
  if postable.class?('Recomendation')
```

But if there is a better solution? Could I use make them inherit from model Postable? But Postable shouldn't be an ActiveRecord model, since its just a wrapper of the 2 classes. And it doesn't involve database at all.

Comment: Can't answer on this level of detail, but it might be worth your while to look at polymorphic associations.

Comment: Do you know about ActiveRecord Associations?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I feel it is more for real things, like comments for different models. But here, the Postable is mere a wrapper, and you can't do something like `Postable.all`.

Comment: If you look at associations, you'll discover scopes. e.g PostTable.All scoped by recommendation will give you all posts for recommendations. Scoped by say user it would give you all posts by user. In general can't and active record don't feature in the same sentence.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Could you elaborate on this? I really have diffulty in understanding this. I can't put them in a  typical has/belongs_to association. Instead, I always think Article/Image/Recommendation is a Postable.

Comment: As I said hard to say exactly but if you have Postables of Article or Recommendation. Defining a polymorphic association adds a "postableType" column to postables. Now Active record knows what it is it can deal with it without you having to test the class. Essentially your code can view Postable as a generic collection of postable things.